# App deployment not working correctly for iOS6 on windows

Tags: ios, ios6, trigger.io

When I deploy app for first time everything works correctly , but after changing code and trying to deploy same app again with "run again" button, app starts without loading forge object so i can not use forge API  .

After little bit of testing I find out that forge  will load  only if I delete app from phone before deployment "run again" button. so basicly. I am using latest version v1.4.15 .

So if you can fix it will save some time during development .

One more , I can install and run app on iOS from windows , but  I can not debug app from windows i am getting

```
Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/C894C75B-DC03-4863-8C3C-09CEF15CC8D9/device- ios.app 
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
```

Comment: I would love to hear how you install & run an iOS app from Windows; that might give some insight how it might be possible to debug from there.

Comment: The question is tagged "trigger.io", so I assume that is the tool being used to develop/deploy/debug iOS apps on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For these iOS and Windows issues, it might be that the device has not been enabled for development - see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/tools/ios-windows.html

If you can borrow an OS X machine for that one-off task, you'll be up and running. If not, apps will install on the device, but you'll need the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone) to see log output.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is related, but I am seeing this message, when running an iOS app from the ToolKit-based UI:
[INFO] Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/0F328847-939D-4557-B58A-33ACACB3B295/device-ios.app
[INFO] Couldn't register io.trigger.forge1078daf40ad711e2acce12313d1adcbe with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
the app does not launch fully; it looks like the forge back-end is not ready or something?

If I wait a few minutes, the app will work perfectly.
weird....

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message. The app installs on the phone, but doesn't launch. The final status on the toolkit UI after "run ios" is "failed". The error line is similar to the one reported here:

```
[ERROR] Failed when running C:\my\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmppqzab4 to: 8e8023ffaa5ad085966046ca3931c9a09b7661a0
...
Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/32F5A9EC-2453-4CD5-9D04-A13D0E14D9AA/device-ios.app
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
```

Here is the full log with "Show debug output" turned on:

```
[INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.34
[DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.34
[DEBUG] main: {"server": "{link}https://trigger.io/api/{/link}"}
[DEBUG] port: 38394
[DEBUG] GET {link}https://trigger.io/api/app/93ec7c70811411e2b05e12313d00dc45/should_rebuild{/link}
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] configuration is identical to last run
[DEBUG] POST {link}https://trigger.io/api/reload/buildevents/93ec7c70811411e2b05e12313d00dc45{/link}
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] Enabled platforms: [u'ios']
[DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.34
[DEBUG] main: {"server": "{link}https://trigger.io/api/{/link}"}
[DEBUG] port: 38394
[DEBUG] POST {link}https://trigger.io/api/track/{/link}
[DEBUG] <ForgeTask (ios)> running...
[DEBUG] <ForgeTask (ios)> script:
[{'do': {'lint_javascript': ()}},
 {'do': {'check_local_config_schema': ()}},
 {'do': {'resolve_urls': ('modules.activations.[].scripts.[]',
                          'modules.activations.[].styles.[]',
                          'modules.icons.*',
                          'modules.launchimage.iphone',
                          'modules.launchimage.iphone-retina',
                          'modules.launchimage.iphone-retina4',
                          'modules.launchimage.ipad',
                          'modules.launchimage.ipad-landscape',
                          'modules.launchimage.ipad-retina',
                          'modules.launchimage.ipad-landscape-retina',
                          'modules.launchimage.android',
                          'modules.launchimage.android-landscape',
                          'modules.button.default_icon',
                          'modules.button.default_popup',
                          'modules.button.default_icons.*')}},
 {'do': {'check_index_html': ('src',)}},
 {'do': {'copy_files': {'from': 'src',
                        'ignore_patterns': [u'.svn/',
                                            u'.cvs/',
                                            u'.hg/',
                                            u'./identity.json',
                                            u'.git/',
                                            u'.bzr/',
                                            u'.forgeignore',
                                            u'./config.json',
                                            u'.darcs/'],
                        'to': 'development/ios/*/assets/src'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'copy_files': {'from': 'src',
                        'ignore_patterns': [u'.svn/',
                                            u'.cvs/',
                                            u'.hg/',
                                            u'./identity.json',
                                            u'.git/',
                                            u'.bzr/',
                                            u'.forgeignore',
                                            u'./config.json',
                                            u'.darcs/'],
                        'to': 'development/reload/src'}}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace_in_dir': {'find': '<head>',
                                     'replace': "<head><script src='%{back_to_parent}%forge/all.js'></script>",
                                     'root_dir': 'development/ios/*/assets/src'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace_in_dir': {'find': '<head>',
                                     'replace': "<head><script src='%{back_to_parent}%forge/all.js'></script>",
                                     'root_dir': 'development/reload/src'}}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace_in_dir': {'find': '<head>',
                                     'replace': '<head>\n\t\t\t\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">\n\t\t\t\t<script>\n\t\t\t\tfunction window$forge$_receive(result) {\n\t\t\t\t\ttry {\n\t\t\t\t\t\twindow.forge._receive(JSON.parse(result));\n\t\t\t\t\t} catch (e) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tforge.logging.error("window$forge$_receive -> " + e);\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t</script>',
                                     'root_dir': 'development/reload/src'}}},
 {'do': {'populate_xml_safe_name': ()}},
 {'do': {'populate_json_safe_name': ()}},
 {'do': {'set_in_biplist': {'filename': 'development/ios/*/Info.plist',
                            'key': 'CFBundleName',
                            'value': '${name}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'set_in_biplist': {'filename': 'development/ios/*/Info.plist',
                            'key': 'CFBundleDisplayName',
                            'value': '${name}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'populate_package_names': ()}},
 {'do': {'set_in_biplist': {'filename': 'development/ios/*/Info.plist',
                            'key': 'CFBundleIdentifier',
                            'value': '${modules.package_names.ios}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'UUID_HERE',
                              'in': ('development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/app_config.json',),
                              'replace': '${uuid}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'UUID_HERE',
                              'in': ('development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/app_config.json',),
                              'replace': '${uuid}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'set_in_biplist': {'filename': 'development/ios/*/Info.plist',
                            'key': 'CFBundleVersion',
                            'value': '1362063560'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'set_in_biplist': {'filename': 'development/ios/*/Info.plist',
                            'key': 'CFBundleShortVersionString',
                            'value': '${version}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'populate_trigger_domain': ()}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'CONFIG_HASH_HERE',
                              'in': ('development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/app_config.json',),
                              'replace': '${config_hash}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'CONFIG_HASH_HERE',
                              'in': ('development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/app_config.json',),
                              'replace': '${config_hash}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'TRIGGER_DOMAIN_HERE',
                              'in': ('development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/app_config.json',),
                              'replace': '${trigger_domain}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'TRIGGER_DOMAIN_HERE',
                              'in': ('development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/app_config.json',),
                              'replace': '${trigger_domain}'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'populate_icons': ('ios', [57, 72, 114, 144])},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'generate_sha1_manifest': {'input_folder': 'development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/src',
                                    'output_file': 'development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/hash_to_file.json'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'generate_sha1_manifest': {'input_folder': 'development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/src',
                                    'output_file': 'development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/hash_to_file.json'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}}]
[INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
[DEBUG] Running: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\bin\jsl.exe" -conf "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\jsl.conf" -process c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\src\*.js -nologo -nofilelisting -nosummary
[WARNING] c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\src\knockout.curly.js(29): SyntaxError: invalid quantifier {
[WARNING]             var ReplacementInfo = ReplaceMatches(node, /{{(.*?)}}/, function (Matches) {
[WARNING] .......................................................^
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\src\Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js(27): SyntaxError: unterminated character class !
[WARNING]         return value.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1");
[WARNING] .............................^
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\src\Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js(5): SyntaxError: unterminated character class !
[WARNING] (function(a){var d=a.validator,b,e="unobtrusiveValidation";function c(a,b,c){a.rules[b]=c;if(a.message)a.messages[b]=a.message}function j(a){return a.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s*,\s*/g)}function f(a){return a.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^
[WARNING] ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^
[WARNING] 
[INFO] JavaScript check complete
[INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[INFO] Configuration settings check complete
[DEBUG] copying src to development/ios\device-ios.app\assets\src
[DEBUG] copying src to development/ios\simulator-ios.app\assets\src
[DEBUG] copying src to development/reload/src
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='%{back_to_parent}%forge/all.js'></script> in development/ios/*/assets/src/**/*.('html',)
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='../forge/all.js'></script> in development/ios\device-ios.app\assets\src\index - original.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='../forge/all.js'></script> in development/ios\device-ios.app\assets\src\index.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='../forge/all.js'></script> in development/ios\simulator-ios.app\assets\src\index - original.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='../forge/all.js'></script> in development/ios\simulator-ios.app\assets\src\index.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='%{back_to_parent}%forge/all.js'></script> in development/reload/src/**/*.('html',)
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='../forge/all.js'></script> in development/reload/src\index - original.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head><script src='../forge/all.js'></script> in development/reload/src\index.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
                <script>
                function window$forge$_receive(result) {
                    try {
                        window.forge._receive(JSON.parse(result));
                    } catch (e) {
                        forge.logging.error("window$forge$_receive -> " + e);
                    }
                }
            </script> in development/reload/src/**/*.('html',)
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
                <script>
                function window$forge$_receive(result) {
                    try {
                        window.forge._receive(JSON.parse(result));
                    } catch (e) {
                        forge.logging.error("window$forge$_receive -> " + e);
                    }
                }
            </script> in development/reload/src\index - original.html
[DEBUG] replacing <head> with <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
                <script>
                function window$forge$_receive(result) {
                    try {
                        window.forge._receive(JSON.parse(result));
                    } catch (e) {
                        forge.logging.error("window$forge$_receive -> " + e);
                    }
                }
            </script> in development/reload/src\index.html
[DEBUG] setting CFBundleName to appname in development/ios/*/Info.plist
[DEBUG] setting CFBundleDisplayName to appname in development/ios/*/Info.plist
[DEBUG] setting CFBundleIdentifier to U9XC4Z6EP5.* in development/ios/*/Info.plist
[DEBUG] replacing UUID_HERE with u'93ec7c70811411e2b05e12313d00dc45'
[DEBUG] replacing UUID_HERE with 93ec7c70811411e2b05e12313d00dc45 in development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/app_config.json
[DEBUG] replacing UUID_HERE with u'93ec7c70811411e2b05e12313d00dc45'
[DEBUG] replacing UUID_HERE with 93ec7c70811411e2b05e12313d00dc45 in development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/app_config.json
[DEBUG] setting CFBundleVersion to 1362063560 in development/ios/*/Info.plist
[DEBUG] setting CFBundleShortVersionString to 0.1 in development/ios/*/Info.plist
[DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.34
[DEBUG] main: {"server": "{link}https://trigger.io/api/{/link}"}
[DEBUG] port: 38394
[DEBUG] replacing CONFIG_HASH_HERE with u'436f5ffbc0886a450ff560d4a18acd10b24e78ca'
[DEBUG] replacing CONFIG_HASH_HERE with 436f5ffbc0886a450ff560d4a18acd10b24e78ca in development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/app_config.json
[DEBUG] replacing CONFIG_HASH_HERE with u'436f5ffbc0886a450ff560d4a18acd10b24e78ca'
[DEBUG] replacing CONFIG_HASH_HERE with 436f5ffbc0886a450ff560d4a18acd10b24e78ca in development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/app_config.json
[DEBUG] replacing TRIGGER_DOMAIN_HERE with u'{link}https://trigger.io'{/link}
[DEBUG] replacing TRIGGER_DOMAIN_HERE with {link}https://trigger.io{/link} in development/ios/device-ios.app/assets/app_config.json
[DEBUG] replacing TRIGGER_DOMAIN_HERE with u'{link}https://trigger.io'{/link}
[DEBUG] replacing TRIGGER_DOMAIN_HERE with {link}https://trigger.io{/link} in development/ios/simulator-ios.app/assets/app_config.json
[DEBUG] <ForgeTask (ios)> has finished
[INFO] Development build created. Use forge run to run your app.
[INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.34
[DEBUG] ignoring non-target directory reload
[DEBUG] Enabled platforms: [u'ios']
[DEBUG] Using configuration file value u'device' for ios.device
[DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.34
[DEBUG] main: {"server": "{link}https://trigger.io/api/{/link}"}
[DEBUG] port: 38394
[DEBUG] POST {link}https://trigger.io/api/track/{/link}
[DEBUG] <ForgeTask (ios)> running...
[DEBUG] <ForgeTask (ios)> script:
[{'do': {'run_ios': (u'device',)}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}}]
[INFO] Running on iOS device: device
[DEBUG] Using configuration file value u'C:\\iPhone Development Files\\Development_Provisioning_Profile.mobileprovision' for ios.profile.provisioning_profile
[DEBUG] Using configuration file value u'C:\\iPhone Development Files\\Developer Certificate.p12' for ios.profile.developer_certificate_path
[DEBUG] Using configuration file value u'appname2' for ios.profile.developer_certificate_password
[DEBUG] Looking for apps at c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\development/ios/device-*/
[DEBUG] Signing c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\development/ios\device-ios.app\
[DEBUG] Provisioning profile has valid wildcard application ID
[INFO] Plist OK
[INFO] 1 Provisioned Device(s):
[INFO] ['8e8023ffaa5ad085966046ca3931c9a09b7661a0']
[INFO] Starting package process for iOS
[INFO] Going to package: c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\development\ios\device-ios.app
[DEBUG] Provisioning profile has valid wildcard application ID
[INFO] Plist OK
[INFO] 1 Provisioned Device(s):
[INFO] ['8e8023ffaa5ad085966046ca3931c9a09b7661a0']
[DEBUG] Extracted seed ID: U9XC4Z6EP5
[DEBUG] Making Payload directory
[DEBUG] Running: attrib +h c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.lib
[DEBUG] File: p12name.jar, already downloaded and correct.
[INFO] Sending app to remote server for codesigning. Uploading may take some time.
[INFO] 100 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp5e1zca
[INFO] 10 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 20 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 30 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 40 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 50 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 60 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 70 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 80 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 90 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 100 percent uploaded: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp63qzfp
[INFO] 100 percent uploaded: C:\my\iPhone Development Files\Developer Certificate.p12
[INFO] Extracting app.zip
[INFO] Running: security create-keychain -p f1af2791b0756cb759e962ecebe61c271f8d2d39 9c863e0e28174ffba943a84ce722660088758729
[INFO] Returned success
[INFO] Running: security import certificate.p12 -k 9c863e0e28174ffba943a84ce722660088758729 -t agg -A -P appname2
[INFO] 1 identity imported.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Returned success
[INFO] Running: security unlock-keychain -p f1af2791b0756cb759e962ecebe61c271f8d2d39 9c863e0e28174ffba943a84ce722660088758729
[INFO] Returned success
[INFO] Running: codesign --keychain 9c863e0e28174ffba943a84ce722660088758729 --force --preserve-metadata --entitlements entitlements.plist --sign iPhone --resource-rules=app/ResourceRules.plist app
[INFO] Returned success
[INFO] Running: /usr/bin/zip --symlinks --verbose --recurse-paths ../out.zip .
[INFO]   adding: _CodeSignature/    (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
[INFO]   adding: _CodeSignature/CodeResources   (in=513) (out=248) (deflated 52%)
[INFO]   adding: embedded.mobileprovision   (in=7428) (out=5034) (deflated 32%)
[INFO]   adding: Forge  (in=1608288) (out=564104) (deflated 65%)
[INFO]   adding: Info.plist (in=1316) (out=857) (deflated 35%)
[INFO]   adding: ResourceRules.plist    (in=161) (out=120) (deflated 25%)
[INFO] total bytes=1617706, compressed=570363 -> 65% savings
[INFO] 
[INFO] Returned success
[INFO] Running: security delete-keychain 9c863e0e28174ffba943a84ce722660088758729
[INFO] Returned success
[INFO] Signed app received, continuing with packaging.
[DEBUG] adding to IPA: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmpyirv0z\Payload\device-ios.app\ForgeCore.bundle\ForgeViewController.nib
[DEBUG] adding to IPA: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmpyirv0z\Payload\device-ios.app\_CodeSignature\CodeResources
[INFO] created IPA: c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmppqzab4
[DEBUG] Running: attrib +h c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.lib
[DEBUG] File: win-ios-install.exe, already downloaded and correct.
[INFO] Installing app on device: is it connected?
[DEBUG] Running: c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.lib\win-ios-install.exe c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmppqzab4 U9XC4Z6EP5.*
[INFO] Installing c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmppqzab4 to: 8e8023ffaa5ad085966046ca3931c9a09b7661a0
[INFO] Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
[INFO] Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
[INFO] Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
[INFO] Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
[INFO] Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
[INFO] Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
[INFO] Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
[INFO] Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
[INFO] Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
[INFO] Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
[INFO] Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
[INFO] Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
[INFO] Install - Complete
[INFO] Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/32F5A9EC-2453-4CD5-9D04-A13D0E14D9AA/device-ios.app
[INFO] Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
[ERROR] Failed when running c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmppqzab4 to: 8e8023ffaa5ad085966046ca3931c9a09b7661a0
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Install - Complete
Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/32F5A9EC-2453-4CD5-9D04-A13D0E14D9AA/device-ios.app
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
[DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\app.py", line 459, in run
    forge_main.run(['--general.interactive', 'no'])
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\main.py", line 414, in run
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.template\generate_dynamic\customer_goals.py", line 125, in run_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 337, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 296, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.template\generate_dynamic\ios_tasks.py", line 695, in run_ios
    certificate_password=certificate_password,
  File "c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.template\generate_dynamic\ios_tasks.py", line 628, in run_idevice
    run_shell(*win_ios_install, fail_silently=False, command_log_level=logging.INFO, check_for_interrupt=True)
  File "c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.template\generate_dynamic\utils.py", line 346, in run_shell
    output=state.output.getvalue()
ShellError: Failed when running c:\projects\forge-workspace\appname\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmppqzab4 to: 8e8023ffaa5ad085966046ca3931c9a09b7661a0
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Install - Complete
Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/32F5A9EC-2453-4CD5-9D04-A13D0E14D9AA/device-ios.app
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
```