# Trigger.io Forge Toolkit - Error running iOS app on iPhone device from Windows 7

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I'm building an iOS app on Windows (yes I know it wasn't meant to be!) with Trigger.io Forge Toolkit.

I an doing 'run iOS' with an iPhone 4 connected by USB. The app builds fine, but the fails after transfering to the device. The app is actually on the device, and runs from the homescreen - but Trigger Toolkit is unable to launch the app itself.

As such, I am not able to see any trigger debugging info when I launch the app on the phone (manually, from the homescreen).

```
[INFO] ERROR: instproxy_browse returned -3
[ERROR] Failed when running C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\strachan\appdata\local\temp\tmpc1pvje to: 2f5ffa12b4567865f96821745a2295b4fc5d67e5
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Install - Complete
ERROR: instproxy_browse returned -3
[DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\app.py", line 286, in run
    forge_main.run(['--general.interactive', 'no'])
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\main.py", line 437, in run
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\customer_goals.py", line 125, in run_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 337, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 296, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\ios_tasks.py", line 626, in run_ios
    certificate_password=certificate_password,
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\ios_tasks.py", line 563, in run_idevice
    run_shell(*win_ios_install, fail_silently=False, command_log_level=logging.INFO, check_for_interrupt=True)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\utils.py", line 346, in run_shell
    output=state.output.getvalue()
ShellError: Failed when running C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\strachan\appdata\local\temp\tmpc1pvje to: 2f5ffa12b4567865f96821745a2295b4fc5d67e5
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Install - Complete
ERROR: instproxy_browse returned -3
```

I tried running on an iPhone 3GS and got the same behaviour, but a slightly different error:

```
[INFO] Installing c:\users\strachan\appdata\local\temp\tmpyg1vs5 to: d6aa150bf9695ce041b37215adb5d6b70f9d6bf4
[INFO] Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
[INFO] Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
[INFO] Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
[INFO] Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
[INFO] Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
[INFO] Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
[INFO] Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
[INFO] Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
[INFO] Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
[INFO] Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
[INFO] Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
[INFO] Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
[INFO] Install - Complete
[INFO] Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/5CC01B44-FC0C-474C-8511-57DA33815625/device-ios.app
[INFO] Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
[ERROR] Failed when running C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\strachan\appdata\local\temp\tmpyg1vs5 to: d6aa150bf9695ce041b37215adb5d6b70f9d6bf4
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Install - Complete
Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/5CC01B44-FC0C-474C-8511-57DA33815625/device-ios.app
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
[DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\app.py", line 286, in run
    forge_main.run(['--general.interactive', 'no'])
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\main.py", line 437, in run
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\customer_goals.py", line 125, in run_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 337, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 296, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\ios_tasks.py", line 626, in run_ios
    certificate_password=certificate_password,
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\ios_tasks.py", line 563, in run_idevice
    run_shell(*win_ios_install, fail_silently=False, command_log_level=logging.INFO, check_for_interrupt=True)
  File "C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.template\generate_dynamic\utils.py", line 346, in run_shell
    output=state.output.getvalue()
ShellError: Failed when running C:\Users\Strachan\Mez\wewana\repo\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\strachan\appdata\local\temp\tmpyg1vs5 to: d6aa150bf9695ce041b37215adb5d6b70f9d6bf4
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - CreatingContainer (50%)
Install - InstallingApplication (60%)
Install - PostflightingApplication (70%)
Install - SandboxingApplication (80%)
Install - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
Install - Complete
Launching - /private/var/mobile/Applications/5CC01B44-FC0C-474C-8511-57DA33815625/device-ios.app
Could not start com.apple.debugserver!
```

Comment: Hey, what version of Windows is this? And what platform_version?

Comment: I'm can't be sure of the platform James as it was some time ago. It would have been whatever was the latest version released on that date (5/12/2012). Machine is Windows 7 home premium.

Comment: There is another similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640940/app-deployment-not-working-correctly-for-ios6-on-windows it also has no answer so this seems to be an outstanding issue since at least September 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the device ever been enabled for development on an OS X machine?

We recently discovered that when Xcode first uses the device, it updates the device to enable remote tailing of logs.

Without doing this, although you'll be able to install apps no problem, you'll need something like the iPhone Configuration Utility to view logs (http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone).

Comment: Thanks JB. This was some time ago now, so I don't remember. Although have been able to successfully build on a different Windows 8 machine now. The app never launches after build however, you always have to go and launch it manually from the home screen.